# Indirect Left recursion

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, left-recursion

I'm resolving indirect left recursion for these production rules:

```
S -> Aa / a   eq1
A -> Sb / b.  eq2
```

Where `S` is the starting symbol.

Now I can do this in two ways:

1. Putting `A` in eq1

   So I'll get the solution (sol1):

   ```
   S -> Sba /a /ba
   ```

   and then

   ```
   S -> aS' / baS' 
   S' -> baS' / epsilon
   ```
2. Replacing `S` in eq2:

   So I'll get the solution (sol2):

   ```
   S -> Aa / a 
   A -> abA' / bA'
   A' -> abA' / epsilon
   ```

Both seem to be correct. Which is the correct answer?

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both your answers are correct. Note that the language under consideration is regular, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

The first grammar is equivalent to this regular expression:
$$r_1 = a(ba)^* \mid (ba)^+.$$

The second grammar is equivalent to this regular expression:
$$r_2 = (ab)^+a \mid b(ab)^*a \mid a.$$

It's easy to prove those regexes generate equal languages $L(r_1) = L(r_2)$.